# What is the proper way to navigate trough several windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets say I have 3 windows forms (called form1, form2 and form3) with 2 buttons in them. Forward and Backward buttons. 
In form1 forward button I have this code:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
```

In form2 forward button I have this code:

```
Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.Show();
            this.Hide();
```

In form3 I have only one button backward

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
```

It is working but I have the feeling that this is not the proper way to navigate true several forms ..

Comment: IF you want to navigate through "pages" better use WPF, it's designed for that type of UI. Usually classic Winforms have a main form and some utility forms, you don't "navigate" through them. But of course this is opinion based. And that's why I vote to close the question.

Answer (score -1):

That method is ok just remember not to close `form1` since that is the main form.
Additionally you can close other forms other than form1 using `this.Close()`;